# python effective binary exponentation with modulo

Tags: python, math

What is the most effective way of implementing the binary exponentiation in python?
This is my approach

```
    def quad_pow(base, exponent, modul): 
        alpha = (bin(exponent).replace('0b', ''))[::-1]
        a = 1
        b = base

        for i in range(0, len(alpha)):
            if int(alpha[i]) == 1:
                a = (a * b) % modul
            b = (b*b) % modul
        return a
```

Is this the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method which is 2X faster than OP and comparable to builtin function

**Code**

```
def power_mod(b, e, m):
  x = 1
  while e > 0:
    if e % 2:
      b, e, x = (b * b) % m, e // 2, (b * x) % m
    else:
      b, e, x = (b * b) % m, e // 2, x

  return x
```

**Timing Summary**

> Normal Integers
>    1. 2X faster than quad_pow
>    2. only ~20% slower than native function
>
> Big Integers
>
> 1. power_mod and quad_power comparable in speed
> 2. pow (Native) is ~2X faster

**Timing Details**

*Normal Integers (i.e. int64)*

```
a = 1234
b = 15
c = 1000000007

Timing: quad_pow 
%timeit quad_pow(a, b, c)
4.69 µs ± 167 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Timing: power_mod
%timeit power_mod(a, b, c)
2.05 µs ± 39.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Timing: pow (Python builtin function)
power(a, b, c)
1.73 µs ± 37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

*Big Integers (i.e. requires arbitrary precision)*

```
a = 2988348162058574136915891421498819466320163312926952423791023078876139
b = 2351399303373464486466122544523690094744975233415544072992656881240319
m = 10 ** 40

Timing: quad_pow 
%timeit quad_pow(a, b, c)
263 µs ± 5.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Timing: power_mod
%timeit power_mod(a, b, c)
263 µs ± 8.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Timing: pow (Python builtin function)
power(a, b, c)
144 µs ± 2.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```